# How to show number of a views return results without submitting the view?

Tags: views

I have a view with some exposed filters.When selecting first exposed filter,I want to appear the Number of the view results without having submitting the view.Same thing for second exposed filter etc.
I have seen this to other sites and I am not sure how to do this with drupal.
thanks

Comment: Do you want to show the result count with exposed filter?

Comment: Yep that's correct

Comment: Then you can use https://drupal.org/project/search_api module for the same.

Comment: I know search api,I want the number of results to be returned without submitting the form

Comment: You can create views for search api and create facet search to display number of results.

Answer (score 0):

How about triggering ajax call on key-press of that input field. In the ajax callback programatically call the view to get total count of results populate this count in field.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Perhaps you could add detail and let the OP know how to do what you are proposing.

Comment: Not appropriate detail.